# How do you do an incremental search across multiple files in VIM?

Tags: vim

Vim already does incremental search within the currently open file but can you do 
an incremental search across multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible. However you can start to type a word that is in an opened buffer and hit <kbd>ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>ctrl-n</kbd> to start searching for such a word in all opened buffers.

Comment: mmm...bummer.  i agree that the ctrl-x ctrl-n is super useful though.

Comment: Sorry, do not use ctrl-x, just hit ctrl-n. Ctrl-x ctrl-n searches only in current buffer, while ctrl-n searches in all other buffers.

Comment: I just discovered putting the cursor on a work and hitting *, it highlights every occurrence of that word in the document.

Comment: And with `#` it searches backwards.

Answer (score -1):

from `:help grepadd`

```
                            *:grepa* *:grepadd*
:grepa[dd][!] [arguments]
            Just like ":grep", but instead of making a new list of
            errors the matches are appended to the current list.
            Example: >
                :call setqflist([])
                :bufdo grepadd! something %
            The first command makes a new error list which is
            empty.  The second command executes "grepadd" for each
            listed buffer.  Note the use of ! to avoid that
            ":grepadd" jumps to the first error, which is not
            allowed with |:bufdo|.
            An example that uses the argument list and avoids
            errors for files without matches: >
                                :silent argdo try 
                  \ | grepadd! something %
                  \ | catch /E480:/
                  \ | endtry"
```

Comment: i'm not sure this does what i asked.  or, if it does i still can't figure it out.  specifically, it's not an incremental search. (on windows it just spawns a findstr)